# datePicker onMonthChange & beforeShowDay getJSON request can't keep up if calendar month quickly clicked through

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'll try and keep this short and to the point.

I've got a `datePicker` set up that is being used for an accommodation website to set check in / check out dates. I'm using `beforeShowDay` to request an XML file that contains date availability and the rate. I've got this set up and working correctly.

When the month is changed I have an `onMonthChange` function to re-request information for the following / previous months dates, this also works as expected, except for one important part:

**The Problem:**
If you quickly click through the months the XML data coming back in can't keep up, so dates incorrectly show as unavailable.

**I need one of the following to happen:**

- Once the data loads the calendar refreshes to show the correct availability
- The month forward button is disabled until the data has been loaded.

**What I've Tried**

- Hiding the month change button at the start of the onMonthChange
  function then showing it at the end - this doesn't work.
- Using `async:false` in the get function - I feel this is the solution
  but I can't get it work as I can't find any clear documentation on
  where it's meant to go.

**Code:**

```
        /* Date Picker */
    var datepickerOptions = {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    };
    var checkInOptions = {
        showOtherMonths: false,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: addPrice,
        onSelect: openCheckout,
        onChangeMonthYear: onMonthChange,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    };

    j.getJSON("/availability.php?startDate="+year+"-0"+month+"-01&id="+j('#property_id').text(),
      { format: "json" },
      function(data) {
            document.pricesData = data;
            document.firstDate = '';
            j('#calendar_check_in').datepicker(checkInOptions);

            /* Tip Tip */
            j('.ui-datepicker-calendar td').tipTip({ defaultPosition: "right" });

            for (var key in document.pricesData) {
               var obj = document.pricesData[key];
               if(obj['avail'] == 1 && document.firstDate == ''){
                  document.firstDate = key;
               }
            }
            d = new Date(document.firstDate.substr(5));
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1);

      });

function addPrice(date) {
    calDate = new Date(date);
    dateString = 'date_'+calDate.getFullYear()+'-'+('0'+(calDate.getMonth()+1).toString()).substr(-2)+'-'+('0'+(calDate.getDate()).toString()).substr(-2);
    if(document.pricesData[dateString] != undefined){
        var priceString = document.pricesData[dateString]['price'];
        if(document.pricesData[dateString]['avail'] == "1"){
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    }else{
        var priceString = 'Price not available';
        valid = false;
    }
    return [valid, '', priceString];
}

function onMonthChange(year, month, inst){
    /* Date Picker */
    month--;
    j.getJSON("/availability.php?startDate="+year+"-0"+month+"-01&id="+j('#property_id').text(),
      { format: "json" },
      function(data) {
            document.pricesData = data;
            document.firstDate = '';
            /* Tip Tip */
            j('.ui-datepicker-calendar td').tipTip({ defaultPosition: "right" });

            for (var key in document.pricesData) {
               var obj = document.pricesData[key];
               if(obj['avail'] == 1 && document.firstDate == ''){
                  document.firstDate = key;
               }
            }
            d = new Date(document.firstDate.substr(5));
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1);
      });
}
```

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to read this, hoping someone has some sort of solution for as it's a bit of a show stopper at the moment!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you quickly click through the months the XML data coming back in
>   can't keep up, so dates incorrectly show as unavailable.

When the user changes months in the datepicker, couldn't you clear the currently displayed pricing and availability information? That way at least you wouldn't have incorrect data displayed. Then, if needed, you could add some message informing the user that the other data is still loading.

I would recommend strongly against trying to use async:false. That is like the nuclear option. It will have other adverse affects to the site and doesn't sound like it is really needed in your case.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response. When I step through the code in the Chrome debugger it appears to change the calendar month before it's loaded the data. The only reason it works at all at the moment is because the original load of the XML contains 3 months of data - previous, current and next.

Comment: @whistlergreg -- So what I was asking was if it was possible to clear the currently displayed data as soon as the user changes months. That way at least there would be no data displayed while you're waiting for the ajax response with the new data. No data is better than incorrect data right?

Comment: That would work fine, but how do I clear the data until it has loaded? Ideally nothing would happen until the onChangeMonthYear function had completed.

Comment: At the very top of onMonthChange function, clear your pricesData and the other data.

Comment: No luck. I added in delete document.priceData; which just kills the calendar completely when i click forward a month. I can't understand why the month change function doesn't complete before doing anything else - if it did I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the thing once that data has been loaded?

Comment: document.priceData = "". Set it to empty....delete in JavaScript does something else.

Comment: Got it:    j('#calendar_check_in').datepicker('refresh');